# Django aggregation in templates?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-aggregation

I'm thinking a bit about the concept of [Django aggregates.](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/) I don't quite "get" how they can be used in my case. Basically i have a three-tier hierarchy of objects in my model, and the lowest object (Bar) contain values I want to aggregate.

```
class Bar(models.Model):
    amount = models.FloatField()

class Foo(models.Model):
    bars = models.ManyToManyField(Bar)

class MyUser(models.Model):
    foos = models.ManyToManyField(Foo)
```

I want my template to do the equivalent of this:

```
{% for user in users %}
    <h2>{{ user }}</h2>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Foo</td><
            <td>Average bar amount</td>
        </tr>
    {% for foo in user.foos.all %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ foo }}</td>
            <td>{{ foo.bars.all.aggregate(Avg('amount')) }}
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </table>
{% endfor %}
```

But of course this template is just pseudo code, it won't work because, I guess, templates are not supposed to do this by design. But on the other hand, having to pre-calculate the average amounts in my view would feel wrong too. How should this problem be approached?

I'm still new to Django so I want to know the "Django way" of doing this :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This work should be done in the view. You say that feels wrong but that's exactly what the view is meant to do: retrieve the data that is going to be presented to the user. Take a look at the Django FAQ:
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/faq/general/#django-appears-to-be-a-mvc-framework-but-you-call-the-controller-the-view-and-the-view-the-template-how-come-you-don-t-use-the-standard-names

> **Django appears to be a MVC framework, but you call the Controller
>   the “view”, and the View the
>   “template”. How come you don’t use the
>   standard names?**
>
> In our interpretation of MVC, the
>   “view” describes the data that gets
>   presented to the user. It’s not
>   necessarily how the data looks, but
>   which data is presented. The view
>   describes which data you see, not how
>   you see it. It’s a subtle distinction.

A side point to this is that based on how you are using the average in your template it would probably make more sense to use `annotate` rather than `aggregate`. http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ref/models/querysets/#annotate-args-kwargs

Answer (score 1):

The templates do not let you call functions that take arguments.  See [here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/topics/templates/#variables) for what they let you do.

The canonical way to deal with this would be to either add some helper methods/managers to your models or to create a [custom template tag or filter](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/howto/custom-template-tags/#howto-custom-template-tags).