# compare values of a dict in a forloop of a django template

Tags: django, django-templates

I need compare values of a dict items inside a loop for in a django template.

```
{% for room in hotel.RoomRS %}
    <p class="precio-old">1000,99€</p>
    <p class="precio-new">{{ room.RoomRates.TotalAmount }}</p>
    <p class="noche">120€ / noche</p>
{% endfor %}
```

This code return some integers values. I need compare it and choose the smallest one

Comment: "This code return some integers values." - what code? Can you add some comment into your snippet and provide an example of the object?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2747339/django-aggregation-in-templates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never put too many logic to Django templates. Instead, do the following in your view and then pass it to context. To get minimum dict value in Python, do:

```
min(my_dict, key=my_dict.get)
```