# Get aggregate in a template

Tags: django

I have this Django model:

```
class Location(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=100)
    customer = models.OneToOneField(Customer, default=None)

class Customer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=100)

class Order(models.Model):
    amount = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, default=0)
```

in my view I get them like this:

```
locations = models.Location.objects.all()
```

and the template lists them like this:

```
{% for location in locations %}
    {{ location.customer.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

I would like to add a sum of all `amount` of all `Order`s connected that customer, something like:

```
{% for location in locations %}
    {{ location.customer.name }} ordered {{ location.customer.orders.sum(amount) }} items
{% endfor %}
```

And according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2747339/django-aggregation-in-templates), I should do that in the view, but how?

Comment: Er, by following the [aggregation docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/aggregation/)? Where exactly are you having problems?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I updated the question with what I tried, trouble is in the fact that I have another model (I posted the incorrect model before).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `.annotate` ([look in docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-for-each-item-in-a-queryset)):

```
from django.db.models import Count

customers = models.Customer.objects.annotate(orders_count=Count('order'))
```

Then in templates you can use it like this:

```
{% for customer in customers %}
    {{ customer.name }} ordered {{ customer.orders_count }} items
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I got it working. Is there a way to filter some `order`s out?

Comment: @BartFriederichs give an example of what you want please

Comment: I only want to count the orders that have a certain state.

Comment: @BartFriederichs probably you can do this with [When object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#when)

Comment: @BartFriederichs look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33775011/how-to-annotate-count-with-a-condition-in-a-django-queryset)

Comment: Looks promising, but I keep getting `__init__() takes either a Q object or lookups as keyword arguments`.

Answer (score 0):

After some folling around I found this works:

```
locations = models.Location.objects.annotate(num_order=Count('customer__order'))
```

and then use this in the template:

```
{% for location in locations %}
    {{ location.customer.name }} ordered {{ location.num_order }} items
{% endfor %}
```